# Subspaces isomorphic with quotients

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space not isomorphic to a Hilbert space. Can we always find a subspace of $X$ that is not isomorphic to a quotient of $X$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every separable Banach space is a quotient of $\ell_1$, so in particular every subspace of $\ell_1$ is a quotient of $\ell_1$.

Comment: And $c_0$ has the dual property--every quotient is isomorphic to a subspace.

Comment: Is there an example, other than a Hilbert space, in which both are true? Every subspace isomorphic with a quotient, and every quotient isomorphic with a subspace?

Comment: @Markus, take $\ell_1\oplus C[0,1]$.